# pandas does not free memory?

Tags: python, pandas

I do have a dataframe with 40000 rows and three columns. If I do `df.set_index('my_ind').head()` repeatedly in different cells in my ipython notebook the RAM is being filled but not freed:

[image]

I thought this function just returns a view of the dataframe. `gc.collect()` did not free any RAM. Any ideas why pandas does not free the RAM ?

Comment: It looks like you're not using the `inplace=True` parameter which is causing you to create a new data frame every time you execute that method. Does your memory use still increase after using `inplace=True`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `inplace=True` in `set_index()`.

Without the `inplace=True` parameter, you're creating a new data frame every time.